# Using Notification Center and Reachability in iOS

Tags: ios, ios7, notifications, nsnotificationcenter

I have this in my view controller.m class in viewDidLoad:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(reachabilityChanged:) name:kReachabilityChangedNotification object:nil];

self.reachability = [Reachability reachabilityWithHostname:@"www.google.com"];

[self.reachability startNotifier];
```

I have also created the notification did change in my view controller.m as well:

```
- (void)reachabilityChanged:(NSNotification*)note
{
Reachability* r = [note object];
NetworkStatus ns = r.currentReachabilityStatus;

if (ns == NotReachable)
{
    NSString* msg = @"Network problems have rendered the iTunes store inaccessible; please try again later.";
    UIAlertView* av = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:nil
                                                 message:msg
                                                delegate:self
                                       cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok"
                                       otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [av show];  }
}
```

Will this after all my views? As I have a navigation controller and it seems to be affecting the start view that I use and the one that I push too. Is this correct? What if it isn't a navigation controller?

Comment: Is `reachabilityChanged:` fired?

Comment: I start at ViewA with internet off, then go to view B and turn internet on and off again, and the message firest again

Comment: I think, It is correct according to your coding. Initially it show alert due to `NotReachable` state. Then again it stats changed to `NotRechable` from ON status.. So It's show again.

Comment: Oh so as it goes through the app, its always listening and responds when necessary....pretty cool then